# How to set permissions to use 'ls'

Tags: linux, file-permissions, user-management

I have a folder (which is owned by another user but the same group) and I want to view it's contents, but I always get the following error message:

```
"ls: cannot open directory .: Permission denied"
```

But the group has rwx-permissions!

Eg:

- folder */var/log/somefolder* is owned by `www-data:www-data`
- user `user1` belongs to group `www-data` (but this is not the main-group).

Which permissions do I have to set, that `user1` is allowed to view the folders contents and write to it?

Comment: can you do a "ls -ld" for each parent folder in the directory tree, also, since adding that user to a group, did you open a new shell? Check "id <user>" and see if said dir really is listed there

Comment: I used the same shell, id user1 includes 33(www-data) and ls -ld seems to work with each parent.

Comment: When you do `newgrp www-data` does the `ls` work then?

Comment: yes, it worked! Can you explain it?!

Comment: do "id" please.

Comment: To access that directory, www-data needs to be your primary group.  The newgrp command temporarily changes your primary group to be www-data.

Comment: @ott-- please create an answer, I'll mark it as solution!

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the `newgrp` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

Obviously, you need to use `newgrp www-data` to make this supplementary group be your primary group. After this, you can `ls` that directory in question.

For me, it works without the `newgrp`:

```
$ ls -l
drwxr-x--- 2 root     adm          4096 Aug 19 14:26 ls-test
$ id
uid=1000(ott) gid=1000(ott) groups=1000(ott),4(adm),5000(vmail)
$ ls -l ls-test/
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Aug 19 14:26 xxx
```

What's your distribution, what version?

Comment: debian 6.0 (I know, not the newest version)

Comment: Mine is 6.0.7, rather old too. Can you put the output of `strace -v ls somedir` (the one that doesn't work) to http://pastebin.com or somwhere else?

Answer (score 3):

The execute permission should be enough to list the directory content. But you have to make sure that all directories in the parent tree have execute permission as well, otherwise `user1` can't traverse the tree down to this directory that you want to `ls`.

For example if you want to check the content of `/var/www` but you have no permissions on the directory `/var`, then you can't do `ls /var/www` because you can't walk the tree from `/` down to `/var/www`.

Another problem might be if SELinux is enabled. Is it enabled?

Comment: ls works in all parent directories perfectly, but not in the target dir! the parent dirs are owned by user1 only the target dir is owned by www-data.

Comment: What about SELinux? is it enabled? you can check by doing `sudo getenforce`

Comment: Nope (sudo: getenforce: command not found)